# Error: PHP login to multiple department

Tags: php, authentication

I have created a login.html page and a login.php script. In the script it will first get the username and password which we enter then check it with database if the username or password is exits or not
 if user is valid then it will check his depatment id , and open their pages with their depatment rights but the problem is its opening the admin page all the time no matter what their department. Please help me in this.

here is my login.html code

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="login.php">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail1">User Name: *</label>
          <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="User Name: *">
        </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
           <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail1">Password: *</label>
          <input required type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"          placeholder="Password: *">
        </div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Submit" style="width: 130px"> 
      Forgot Username or Password ?</form>
```

login.php script

```
<?php
session_start();

ob_start();

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hct_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 // Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];


// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password);
$sql="SELECT username, password FROM employee where username='".$username."' and      password='".$password."'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
$sql2="SELECT department FROM employee WHERE username='".$username."'";
$result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
   if($result2==1){

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
header("location:admin/index.php");
}
if ($result2==2){

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
 header("location:developer/index.html");
}
if ($result2==3){
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
header("location:sales/index.html");
}

   else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
    ob_end_flush();
    ?>
```

Comment: In database, employee table has a column named department where the values are 1 or 2 or 3. if the value is 1 it will open the admin page, if its 2 then developer page and so on/.

Comment: What a wonderful code salad. Lots of ingredients there, from cabbage to what not.

Comment: whats the problem of yours N.B. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not fetching the result.

```
$result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
   if($result2==1)
```

Only checks wether the sql-query was sucessfull, which it is, returning true, which also translate as 1.
Do this:

```
$row = $result2->fetch_assoc();
if($row["department"]=="1") 

and so on...
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' on this line row = $result2->fetch_assoc();